# Armature Deform with Weights

Tags: armature

I have my mesh all rigged up. I select my mesh and then my rig and apply *Armature Deform With Automatic Weights*. Unfortunately my mesh is laying down and not paired up with the rig. I think the issue is that the rotation is set to 1 on the mesh. If yes, how do I make it be 0 without actually moving the mesh?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The body is already parented, it will come back to its default rotation as soon as you'll parent it to the armature, you need to unparent before parenting: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*

Comment: Thank you! This worked!!!!